# Elasticsearch Java High Level Rest Client Multi Level Nested Queries

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

Currently I'm experimenting with Java High Level Rest Client to Elasticsearch and saw there is something like that:

```
NestedQueryBuilder nestedQuery = QueryBuilders
.nestedQuery("events.recommendationData", queryString, ScoreMode.None);
```

But couldn't make it with multi-level nested queries, for example:

```
PUT /app
{
      "mappings": {
         "sample": {
            "properties": {
               "sampleSources": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "source": {
                        "type": "nested"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }

   }
}
```

Does anyone knows how to construct this search with java api:

```
GET /app/sample/_search
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "sampleSources.source",
         "query": {
             "match": {
                "sampleSources.source.name": "default"
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your mappings as below :

```
"sampleSources":{
        "type":"nested",
        "properties":{
          "source":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
              "name":{
                "type":"text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

The nested query can be done as below, for evey nested parent a query is performed:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "sampleSources.source.name": {
                      "query": "default",
                      "operator": "AND"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "path": "sampleSources.source"
              }
            },
            "path": "sampleSources"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: I have added bool clause, but it may/not needed for you.

Approach for RESTHighLevelClient, you should take is build a nested query by looping through all the nested parent path.

Comment: @Andrzej Ustupski, let me know if you want the example Java code, I have not put that as there are multiple steps involved.